# sorting according to time sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, time

how can sort my code in time sequence(12 1 2 3 ... 10 11)? I got random input and sort it into am/pm. Here's my code:

```
    time = input("Please enter the boost times: ")
    lst = time.split()
    
    def lenght(t):
        if len(lst[i]) == 7:
            h = lst[i][5]
            return h
        elif len(lst[i]) == 6:
            h = lst[i][4]
            return h

    lsta = []
    lstp = []
    
    def ampm(t):
        if ord(lenght(lst[i])) == ord('a'):
            if str(lst[i][1]) == str("2"):
                lsta.insert(0,lst[i])
            else:
                lsta.append(lst[i])
        elif ord(lenght(lst[i])) == ord('p'):
            if str(lst[i][1]) == str("2"):
                lstp.insert(0,lst[i])
            else:
                lstp.append(lst[i])
    
    
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(last):
        lenght(lst[i])
        ampm(lst[i])
        i += 1
```

and here's my example result from this code by now;

Please enter the boost times: 11:00am 12:59am 5:02pm 7:02am 8:00pm

['12:59am', '11:00am', '7:02am'] ['5:02pm', '8:00pm']

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help in the future, you'll need to provide a [mre] including expected output and minimal but complete code (e.g. `last` is not defined and `lenght(lst[i])` is pointless in the while-loop).